# Finding an explicit formula given this recursive definition

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations

I have been considering the following problem: say you are picking from an infinite population of red and blue balls. A ball has a probability $p$ of being red; otherwise it is blue. If I choose $n$ balls at random, what is the probability that exactly $k$ of them are red? Denote this probability as $a(n, k, p)$. Thinking about this, one can see that 
$$a(n, k, p) = p\cdot a(n-1, k-1, p) + (1-p)\cdot a(n-1, k, p)$$
$$a(k, k, p) = p^k$$
$$a(0, n, p) = (1-p)^n$$
(if I'm not mistaken, the above three facts should be enough to uniquely define this function)

If possible, I would like to find an explicit formula for this function. I have tried making a generating function, I've tried finding formulas for special cases (I found some such formulas, but they didn't help me get a general formula).

I apologize if this is a duplicate, I couldn't find anything on this problem.

Comment: Given the assumption that you have infinitely many balls, this seems to be equivalent to sampling with replacement, and thus to a [Binomial distribution with parameters $n,p$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Probability_mass_function).

Comment: @ClementC. Perfect, thank you so much!